# Best place to check for env variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I use ENV variables for all environments to set up different components of the stack, i.e. Redis, Memcached, etc.

I load all of these in the `config/application.rb` file, and before that I ensure that all environment variables are present.

I'm running into a problem now where I run a rake task before these variables are set, and so it fails my test. Rake seems to doing it's share correctly. This leads me to believe all of these variables initializations are in the wrong spot.

Now I'm at a loss as to the best place to instantiate all these services or check for their existence.

Answer (score 0):

Init them right after `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in your `application.rb` like this https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#note-on-load-order

You can check env variables in Rails console, for example:

```
ENV['YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE']
```

Comment: Part of the problem for me is that is where I'm doing that already, however it seems that since I run some Rake tasks in a context outside of environment variables they don't work (since they load `application.rb`) thoughts?

Comment: Can you show me a part of your rake task? Did you pass ```[:environment]``` to the task?